# How to use AllowN in go?

Tags: go, goroutine

I try to use AllowN, it work well when I start 100 goroutine, but if I start 1000 goroutine, it lose control.

Test code

```
func main() {
    var count int64 = 0
    limit := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Limit(100), 100)

    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func() {
            for true {
                if limit.Allow() {
                    atomic.AddInt64(&count, 1)
                }
            }
        }()
    }

    start := time.Now().UnixMilli()
    for true {
        last := count
        <-time.Tick(time.Second)

        fmt.Printf("current time[%d] allow %d  \n", time.Now().UnixMilli()-start, count-last)
    }
}
```

result

```
current time[1000] allow 7507  
current time[2001] allow 6708  
current time[3001] allow 7701  
current time[4001] allow 7571  
current time[5001] allow 9072  
current time[6001] allow 7779  
current time[7002] allow 8238  
current time[8002] allow 7521  
current time[9002] allow 24473  
current time[10003] allow 45594
```

I try to change goroutine num and sleep a mill, it work well

Comment: You have a memory race. Read the count with atomic read.

Comment: "it lose control" --- what does this exactly mean? Those results are not unexpected for the code? You also have a race condition around accessing `count` variable.